# If I'm using the same react/redux component twice, will they share state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

If I had a component, which was loaded into a page, accepted a few props, made a couple of API calls and rendered a list, would they share the same redux store?

Say for example...

```
<Trending data-limit=5 data-offset=0 />
<div>Something here</div>
<Trending data-limit=5 data-offset-5 />
```

I have something similar to this and they seem to override each other.

Comment: One of the main Redux principles is that there is only one store in your app, so if you following that then answer is yes, they will share. If you not sure, provide more info about what is inside those components and what are you getting vs. expecting.

Comment: They share the same _store_, yes, but not necessarily the same _state_. You can absolutely have multiple instances of the same component which each have individual state. Without seeing the shape of your store and how the components communicate with the store, it is impossible to suss out the problem.

Comment: Depends on how `Trending` uses state.

Comment: It depends from how your `connect` configuration looks like. It should do only immutable operations.

Comment: please refer to this article:
[SO Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906358/having-multiple-instance-of-same-reusable-redux-react-components-on-the-same-pag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together an example to show how to use the same component with two different Redux containers that could be used to populate the store differently. I am actually confused now because the two reducers overwrite the same state, despite being separated by combineReducers.

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';

const ParentComponent = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    fetchData: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    data: React.PropTypes.string
  },
  componentDidMount: function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.fetchData();
    }, 2000);
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.data}</div>
    );
  }
});

const ParentComponentContainer = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (<ParentComponent {...this.props} />);
  }
});

const mapStateToPropsFoo = (state) => {
  if (state.exampleReducerFoo && state.exampleReducerFoo.data) {
    return {
      data: state.exampleReducerFoo.data
    }
  }
  return {};
};
const mapStateToPropsBar = (state) => {
  if (state.exampleReducerBar && state.exampleReducerBar.data) {
    return {
      data: state.exampleReducerBar.data
    }
  }
  return {};
};
const mapDispatchToPropsFoo = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchData: () => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'RECEIVE_DATA',
        data: 'foo'
      });
    }
  }
};
const mapDispatchToPropsBar = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchData: () => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'RECEIVE_DATA',
        data: 'bar'
      });
    }
  }
};

const reducers = combineReducers({
  exampleReducerFoo: (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'RECEIVE_DATA':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
          data: action.data
        });
      default:
        return state;
    }
  },
  exampleReducerBar: (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'RECEIVE_DATA':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
          data: action.data
        });
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
});
const store = createStore(reducers);
const ConnectedParentComponentContainerFoo = connect(mapStateToPropsFoo, mapDispatchToPropsFoo)(ParentComponentContainer);
const ConnectedParentComponentContainerBar = connect(mapStateToPropsBar, mapDispatchToPropsBar)(ParentComponentContainer);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><div><ConnectedParentComponentContainerFoo data="aaa"/>something<ConnectedParentComponentContainerBar data="bbb"/></div></Provider>, document.getElementById('ReactApp'));
```

When the state gets to the mapStateToProps functions it's shape is:

```
{
  exampleReducerBar: {
    data: 'bar'
  },
  exampleReducerFoo: {
    data: 'bar'
  }
}
```

I expected the reducers to be writing to their own space in the state (reducerBar's data should be 'bar' and reducerFoo's data should be 'foo'), but apparently even though the reducers shape the state when using combineReducers, the state is shared between reducers. I am confused.

Comment: I am looking at the exact same code,  did you ever figure this out?

Comment: It's a global store. Your action cannot have the same name. Change the name for one of the reducers from RECEIVE_DATA to RECEIVE_DATA_FOO and it will work

Answer (score 3):

If you mean React State, then no.

If you mean Redux Store State, by mapStateToProps or other way and your react component are connected to the same end point in the storeState then Yes

ex : let's say you have mapStateToPros linking the props of the component to this end point of the store State.App.User.Info.email

If email changes all component mapped to this end point will update

In the other hand if you're calling each component with it's own data, then each component lives in it's own space like the example you gave in your question