# having multiple instance of same reusable redux react components on the same page/route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

We are creating a large front-end application.

We are using React-Redux for it

We are creating some reusable components.

*This question is regarding having multiple instance of same reusable redux react components on the same page/route*

#### Problem details:

We have a `Sectionheader` component. Which is bound to redux state.

It listens to the header property reducer `SectionheaderReducer`.

As we have 2 instances of this `Sectionheader` on the page both tend to show same values as they are bound to the same store state-property.

How to make the redux based reusable react component configurable? So that each instance can have different value of header property for reducer `SectionheaderReducer`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to implement some way of namespacing the instances.  This can be as basic as passing in a key to differentiate the components and reducers.

You can use the `ownProps` in your `mapStateToProps` function to guide the mapping to a namespace

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) {
    let myState = state[ownProps.namespace]
    return {
        myState.value
    }
}
```

The same method can be used to pass on a namespace to the `mapDispatchToProps`

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) {
    return {
        myAction: (myParam) => dispatch(myAction(ownProps.namespace, myParam))
    }
}
```

Just remember to use the namespace in the action type so the reducers don't tread on toes

```
const myAction => (namespace, myParam) {
    return { type: `${namespace}/${MY_TYPE_CONSTANT}`, myParam }
}
```

And make sure the reducer is namespaced too

```
const myReducer = (namespace) => (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case `${namespace}/${MY_TYPE_CONSTANT}`:
            return { ...state, action.myParam }
        default:
            return state
    {
}
```

Now add the 2 namespaced reducers when combining reducers

```
combineReducers({
    myInstance1 : myReducer('myInstance1')
    myInstance2 : myReducer('myInstance2')
}
```

Finally pass the namespace to each instance

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <MyComponent namespace='myInstance1' />
            <MyComponent namespace='myInstance2' />
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I am the main contributor on the following library.

[redux-subspace](https://github.com/ioof-holdings/redux-subspace#namespacing) can provide a more advanced namespacing implementation without you having to reimplement this pattern for every component you want to have multiple instances for.

Creating the reducers is similar to above

```
const reducer = combineReducers({ 
    myInstance1: namespaced('myInstance1')(myReducer)
    myInstance2: namespaced('myInstance2')(myReducer)
})
```

Then `SubspaceProvider` can be used to switch out the state for each component

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <SubspaceProvider mapState={state => state.myInstance1} namespace='myInstance1'>
                <MyComponent />
            </SubspaceProvider>
            <SubspaceProvider mapState={state => state.myInstance2} namespace='myInstance2'>
                <MyComponent />
            </SubspaceProvider>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Just ensure you also change your `mapStateToProps` function to so start traversing from the subtree mapped in the provider

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) {
    return {
        state.value
    }
}
```

There is also a [Higher-Order Component](https://github.com/ioof-holdings/redux-subspace#higher-order-component-1) if you prefer to reduce nesting.

Comment: Hi Michael - I'm facing the same problem where I have multiple instances of a component on a page using the same action & reducer. I tried your solution but couldn't quite make it work. Any chance you could take a quick look and perhaps update the code of my Question? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44640679/react-multiple-components-with-the-same-actions-reducers

Comment: This answer... is why I would never use Redux or any of these singleton patterns. It is completely against the notion of software development to need to do this kind of thing to support two instances of something. This is solved in Vue, React State, Angular (2/4+), Polymer and web components in general. Yet the React community continues to push Redux for no apparent reason.

Comment: I agree with using props in mapStateToProps is needed, but all the logic can be done within the component the OP is writing so that the OP's component only requires a unique key passed as a prop, without forcing users of the component to have to combine multiple reducers.  Internally the OP's component would use mapStateToProps to include the key in it's dispatch actions, but the component's reducer can be responsible for allocating effective sub-namespaces within it's own namespace, and (factory) selectors responsible for ensuring each component uses the correct sub-namespace.

Comment: @dsollen there are dozens of ways this can be achieved, I just proposed the way I would do it, keeping the presentational component as dumb as possible and pushing the logic to redux.

Comment: @MichaelPeyper what if you have N instances where N can and will change and determined by an API call? In this case, I'm not sure how many instances of my component I'm going to have. Any ideas how to deal with this situation? Currently, I'm using local state for that component which works fine.

Comment: @StevenScaffidi if local state is working fine for you then there's no reason to change it.  When dealing with dynamic state shape, you have (at least) 2 options. 1) look into [dynamic reducers](https://github.com/ioof-holdings/redux-dynamic-reducer), or 2) move the reducer up a level and pass a key with the action to differentiate the state slices.  It's a bit too complicated to show examples in comments so I suggest raising a new question if you want to explore this further.

Comment: @MichaelPeyper I think theres a typo in `<MyComponent' />` (a trailing '  after `MyComponent`). My 2 cents.

Comment: For anyone coming across this now, as a response to the comment by @coding: that's correct, the redux singelton pattern isn't very reusable, but that's not the problem it's solving. Redux is really useful when you want components anywhere in your tree to modify / use the same data without passing around tons of props and callbacks (i.e. exactly when you want a singleton / global). Internal component state is a better approach when you need to render N copies of a component that all behave the same way. This answer is a happy medium for when you need, say, 3 copies of the same reducer.

Comment: @jlucier avoiding passing props through components tree is solved by Context API, Redux not related to it at all

Comment: I find that the higher-order named reducer explained [here](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/reusing-reducer-logic) works better with TypeScript

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented it in a different way, without actually changing the action name with a namespace.

Rather, I added infra functions which will intercept the action creators and add `meta-data` to each action. (following `FSA`)
That way you don't need to change your reducer or the `mapStateToProps` function.

Also it is compatible with `redux-thunk`.

Should be easy to use... [reducer-action-interceptor](https://github.com/jony89/reducer-action-interceptor)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/), you could consider this pattern.  Your `createSlice` `initialState` would be an object, an empty object to start with.

```
createSlice({
   name: "counters",
   initialState: {},
   reducers: {}
})
```

You would then have a few reducers that create and delete initial state (which would be triggered on mounting and unmounting of the component)

```
createSlice({
   name: "counters",
   initialState: {},
   reducers: {
    // will be use on mounting of the component
    createState(state, { payload: id }: { payload: number | string }) {
      // create state only if there's no state for the id
      if (!state[id]) {
        state[id] = 0; // this is where you actually define the initial state instead of up there ...
      }
    },
    deleteState(state, { payload: id }: { payload: number | string }) {
      delete state[id];
    },
   }
})
```

You can have a look at [this file on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-68admb?file=src%2Ffeature%2Fcounter%2FcountReducer.tsx) for the complete code.

Next, we'll add the increment and decrement actions and a `selector function` named `selectCounters`:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { IRootState } from '../store';

export const {
  reducer: countersReducer,
  actions: { 
    increment, decrement, 
    createState: createCounterState, 
    deleteState: deleteCounterState },
} = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    createState(state, { payload: id }: { payload: number | string }) {
      // create state only if there's no state for the id
      if (!state[id]) {
        state[id] = 0; // this is where you actually define the initial state instead of up there ...
      }
    },
    deleteState(state, { payload: id }: { payload: number | string }) {
      delete state[id];
    },
    increment(state, { payload: id }: { payload: number | string }) {
      state[id] = state[id] + 1;
    },
    decrement(state, { payload: id }: { payload: number | string }) {
      state[id] = state[id] - 1;
    },
  },
});

export const selectCounters = (state: IRootState) => state.counters;
```

Next, lets work on our integrated `Counter component`.  Note these two point:

1. we create the component state on mounting i.e. inside the `useEffect` and delete it when it unmounts.
2. The `<Counter />` accepts an `id prop` to differentiate between counters

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {
  createCounterState,
  decrement,
  increment,
  selectCounters,
  deleteCounterState,
} from './countReducer';

export const Counter = ({ id }: { id: number | string }) => {
  const counters = useSelector(selectCounters);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(createCounterState(id));
    return () => {
      dispatch(deleteCounterState());
    };
  }, []);


  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', gap: '8px', fontSize: '20px' }}>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => dispatch(decrement(id))}>
        -
      </button>
      {counters[id]}
      <button type="button" onClick={() => dispatch(increment(id))}>
        +
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

That is it!!  Now, we can use the `re-usable <Counter id={"hello or any other number or string id"} />` as many times we like:

```
export const App: FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {/** You can pass a numeric or string id */}
      <Counter id={1} />
      <br />
      <Counter id={'foo'} />
      <br />
      <Counter id={'bar'} />
      <br />
      <Counter id={10} />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Here's the working example on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-68admb?file=src%2FApp.tsx

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted the question to mean:

- you have content data in the store (e.g. the sections and their titles)
- you have components for drawing bits of the data (e.g. your `<SectionHeader />`)
- you want to display more than one section on a page but currently all your headers have the same text

One possible solution would have you add the idea of "sections" to your store. You'd create reducers that manage the content structure of the data. E.G. the store state, at one time, may look like this:

```
{ 
  sections: {
     0: {
        header: 'My section title',
        content: 'Whatever your content is'
     },
     1: {
        header: 'My other section title',
        content: 'Loads of lovely writing or hrefs to images or whatever'
     }
  }
}
```

```

You would then have a "container component" or "layout component" or "smart component" (they have many names), that "knows" that you want to use section 2 and section 4 on a particular page. How it knows this, is up to you. Perhaps you hard-code the indices (because it will always be the same), perhaps you have a filtering rule, perhaps you have another field in the store which defines the choices... etc.

The container component would then pass the chosen heading into the "dumb" , perhaps like this:

```
<SectionHeader>{sections[2].header}</SectionHeader>
```

or

```
<SectionHeader title={sections[2].header} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert our component into dumb(stateless) component so that those will reused easily without any complications.