# Reusable React component with same actions & reducers

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reducers

I want to reuse a react component and share common actions & reducers. My app dashboard has 3 Lists, where each List is fetched with different query param.

All 3 List components have the same props because all 3 of them are being re-rendered once I receive props from reducer.

Is there an dynamic way to display Lists based on query parameter? What I was thinking is to call different reducer in the action file based on the query param. Is there a better way?

**Dashboard.js**

```
 const Dashboard = () => {
      return(
        <div>
          <List query={QUERY1} />
          <List query={QUERY2} />
          <List query={QUERY3} />
        </div>
      )
    }
```

**List.js**

```
class List extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const { query } = this.props;
    this.props.onLoad(query);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    const { items } = this.props;
    this.setState({ items });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
          {
            this.state.items.map((item, index) =>
              <Item data={item} key={index}/>
            )
          }
      </div>
    )
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { items } = state.item;
  return {
    items
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onLoad: bindActionCreators(actions.load, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(List);
```

**action.js**

```
export function load(query) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    fetch(`//api.example.com/list?type=${query}&limit=10`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        dispatch(setItems(data));
      });
  };
}
```

**reducer.js**

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.ITEMS_SET:
      return setItems(state, action);
  }
  return state;
}

function setItems(state, action) {
  const { items } = action;
  return { ...state, items };
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [having multiple instance of same reusable redux react components on the same page/route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906358/having-multiple-instance-of-same-reusable-redux-react-components-on-the-same-pag)

Answer (score 1):

*Note I am a contributor on redux-subpace*

[redux-subspace](https://github.com/ioof-holdings/redux-subspace) came around to solve this problem of having the same component displayed on the page, without crossing over the store values.

It has a feature called [namespacing](https://github.com/ioof-holdings/redux-subspace#namespacing) that will allow you to isolate your load actions and components from each other.

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  return(
    <div>
      <SubspaceProvider mapState={state => state.list1}, namespace='list1'>
        <List query={QUERY1} />
      </SubspaceProvider>
      <SubspaceProvider mapState={state => state.list2}, namespace='list'>
        <List query={QUERY2} />
      </SubspaceProvider>
      <SubspaceProvider mapState={state => state.list3}, namespace='list3'>
        <List query={QUERY3} />
      </SubspaceProvider>
    </div>
  )
}
```

You'll also need to namespace your reducers, you can see how to do that [here](https://github.com/ioof-holdings/redux-subspace#reducers).