# react child component is overwriting redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

When my parent renders it overwrites the child messages i got 2 same messages for every parent component. Please help me. Following is my parent component.
For example my parent has 4 Projects.

```
{
project1: { message1: 'hello this message for project 1',message2: 'messsage 2 for project 1'},    
project2: { message1: 'hello this message for project 2',message2: 'messsage 2 for project 2'}
};
```

But in output i got

```
project1: { message1: 'hello this message for project 2',message2: 'messsage 2 for project 2'};
project2: { message1: 'hello this message for project 2',message2: 'messsage 2 for project 2'};
```

I want that project 1 will show its own messages and project 2 its own, but redux is overwriting my states.

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
  import { connect } from 'react-redux';
  import { projectsFetchData } from '../actions/projects';
  import MessageList from './MessageList';

  class Projects extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchData('https://api.proworkflow.net/projects?apikey=9ZVM-873H-3JPK-C55Q-PWFE7MN-TR86485');
      }
      render() {
          if (this.props.hasErrored) {
              return <p>Sorry! There was an error loading the items</p>;
          }
          if (this.props.isLoading) {
              return <p>Loading…</p>;
          }
          return (
            <div className="container">
              <div className="panel panel-primary">
                <div className="panel-heading clearfix">
                  <div className="header-logo pull-left" />
                  <div className="pull-right heading">
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    &nbsp;Project Messages
                  </div>
                 </div>
                <div className="panel-body secondry">
                  {this.props.projects.map((item) => (
                    <div className="media" key={item.id}>
                      <div className="media-body">
                        <h4 className="media-heading"><i>{item.companyname}</i></h4>
                        <p><i>{item.title}</i></p>
                        <MessageList projectId={item.id} />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
      }
  }
  Projects.propTypes = {
      fetchData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      projects: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
      hasErrored: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
      isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
  };

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
          projects: state.projects,
          hasErrored: state.projectsHasErrored,
          isLoading: state.projectsIsLoading
      };
  };

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
          fetchData: (url) => dispatch(projectsFetchData(url))
      };
  };

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Projects);
```

Following is my Child component

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
  import { connect } from 'react-redux';
  import { messagesFetchData } from '../actions/messages';

  class MessageList extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        const projectId = this.props.projectId;
        this.props.fetchData(`https://api.proworkflow.net/projects/${projectId}/messages?apikey=9ZVM-873H-3JPK-C55Q-PWFE7MN-TR86485`);
      }
      render() {
          if (this.props.hasErrored) {
              return <p>Sorry! There was an error loading the items</p>;
          }
          if (this.props.isLoading) {
              return <p>Loading…</p>;
          }
          return (
            <div className="media-container">
              {this.props.messages.map((item) => (
              <div className="media" key={item.id}>
                <div className="media-left">
                  <a role="button">
                    <img className="media-object img-circle" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8c2f99e721ce7c2e8968ae2eec40c4dc?s=80&d=mm" alt="..."/>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div className="media-body">
                  <h4 className="media-heading">{item.authorname}</h4>
                  <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: item.content}}/>
                </div>
              </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          );
      }
  }
  MessageList.propTypes = {
      fetchData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      hasErrored: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
      isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
  };

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
          messages: state.messages,
          hasErrored: state.messagesHasErrored,
          isLoading: state.messagesIsLoading
      };
  };

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
          fetchData: (url) => dispatch(messagesFetchData(url))
      };
  };

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MessageList);
```

Following is my child reducer

```
    export function messagesHasErrored(state = false, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'MESSAGES_HAS_ERRORED':
                return action.hasErrored;
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
    export function messagesIsLoading(state = false, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'MESSAGES_IS_LOADING':
                return action.isLoading;
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
    export function messages(state = [], action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'MESSAGES_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
              return action.messages;
            default:
              return state;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because both projects are sharing the same redux-state.

I am not sure whether adding the namespace would help you, as your project list may have an arbitrary number of projects. However, I think it may give you some hints on solving the shared state problem.

[having multiple instance of same reusable redux react components on the same page/route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906358/having-multiple-instance-of-same-reusable-redux-react-components-on-the-same-pag)

---

Instead of having a message Reducer, you could add a projectMessages Reducer.

In child reducer

```
export function projectMessages(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'PROJECT_MESSAGES_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
          return Object.Assign({}, state, {action.payload.projectId: action.payload.messages});
        default:
          return state;
    }
}
```

In Actions:

```
export function projectMessagesFetchDataSuccess(messages, projectId) {
    return {
        type: "PROJECT_MESSAGES_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS",
        payload: { projectId: projectId, messages: message }
    };
}
```

In MessageComponent: get the messages for the project by

```
this.prop.projectMessages[this.props.projectId]
```

---

For example:

```
projectMessages = {"project1": ["m1", "m2", "m3"], "project2": ["m4", "m5", "m6"]};
```

If you want to get message for project2, you can do

```
var messagesOfProject2 = projectMessages["project2"];
```

Comment: But how i can get messages of particular project.? please help me

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in designs.

1. In the parent  component,you written

   `<MessageList projectId={item.id} />`

which is render whenever there is changes in `projects` state.

2. In the `MessageList` component itself,you are using state  `messages: state.messages`

which will ask component re-render again whenever there is change in the `state.messages`.

So,in this way,your message component is render twice.

Solution :

In the parent component, remove properties that you are passing.

instead of `<MessageList projectId={item.id} />` write `<MessageList />`

From `projects: state.projects` statement, `projects` is the part of  state.

So,loop it in child component (`MessageList`).

In child component,your `mapStatesToProps` will be

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
          messages: state.messages,// remove it
          hasErrored: state.messagesHasErrored,
          isLoading: state.messagesIsLoading,
          projects : state.projects //added in child component
      };
  };
```

remove `messages: state.messages` from state tree as its only internal state for `MessageList` component.You can stored it internally and loop it

In the child component,in the

```
componentDidMount() {
    let projectId = null;
    this.props.projects.map((item) =>{
        projectId = item.id;
            this.props.fetchData(`https://api.proworkflow.net/projects/${projectId}/messages?apikey=9ZVM-873H-3JPK-C55Q-PWFE7MN-TR86485`);

    }) 
  }
```

Now,whenever there is changes in the `projects` state in parent component,
your child component (MessageList) will re-render with updated project id data.

Comment: But how i can get messages of particular project.? please help me