# Last child component overwrites all children

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a parent react component containing 3 children:

```
<ChildComponent category="foo" />
<ChildComponent category="bar" />
<ChildComponent category="baz" />
```

The child component calls an api depending on the prop category value:

```
http://example.com/listings.json?category=foo
```

In my action the data is returned as expected. However, when the child component renders the data. The last child baz is overwriting its value in foo and bar as well.

A [solution to this problem seems to be given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42939732/538471). But I would like this to be dynamic and only depend on the category prop. Is this not possible to do in Redux?

My **child component** looks like this:

```
class TweetColumn extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchTweets(this.props.column)
  }

  render() {
    const { tweets, column } = this.props
    if (tweets.length === 0) { return null }
    const tweetItems = tweets[column].map(tweet => (
      <div key={ tweet.id }>
        { tweetItems.name }
      </div>
    )
    return (
      <div className="box-content">
        { tweetItems }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

TweetColumn.propTypes = {
  fetchTweets: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  tweets: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  tweets: state.tweets.items
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchTweets })( TweetColumn )
```

**reducers**:

```
export default function tweetReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_TWEETS_SUCCESS:
      return {
    ...state,
    [action.data[0].user.screen_name]: action.data
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default combineReducers({
    tweets: tweetReducer,
})
```

**action:**

```
export const fetchTweets = (column) => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_TWEETS_START })
  const url = `${ TWITTER_API }/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=30&screen_name=${ column }`
  return axios.get(url)
    .then(response => dispatch({
      type: FETCH_TWEETS_SUCCESS,
      data: response.data
    }))
    .then(response => console.log(response.data))
    .catch(e => dispatch({type: FETCH_TWEETS_FAIL}))

}
```

Comment: use a `key` prop ??

Comment: @xadm Just pass in key prop to the child components? That didn't work.

Comment: keys should be used for all the same type childs to help distinguish them...  case .. redux ... you probably looking for [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect)

Comment: Could you show us how you update `tweets` in your redux reducer? I'm guessing you are overriding it on every action resulting from a successful api response.

Comment: @nebuler updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making an api call every time `TweetColumn` is mounted. If you have multiple `TweetColumn` components and each one makes an api call, then whichever one's response is last to arrive is going to set the value of `state.tweets.items`. That's because you are dispatching the same action `FETCH_TWEETS_SUCCESS` every time (the last one overrides the previous one). To solve that issue, assuming the response has a `category` (foo, bar, baz), I would write the reducer in the following way:

```
export default function tweetReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_TWEETS_SUCCESS:
      return {
          ...state,
          [action.data.category]: action.data
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

You can then do the following in your `TweetColumn` component:

```
class TweetColumn extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchTweets(this.props.column)
  }

  render() {
    const { column } = this.props;
    const tweetItems = this.props.tweets[column].map(tweet => (
      <div key={ tweet.id }>
        { tweet.name }
      </div>
    )
    return (
      <div className="box-content">
        { tweetItems }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  tweets: state.tweets
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchTweets: column => dispatch(fetchTweets(column))
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)( TweetColumn )
```

You will have to do some validation to make sure `tweets[column]` exists, but you get the idea.

Comment: The response does contain the category. However the data seem to populate after it renders `tweetItems`, so `this.props.tweets[column]` is always undefined. Putting a `if (tweets.length === 0) { return null }` causes it to never render.

Comment: @dan-klasson could you add the implementation of `fetchTweets` to your question?

Comment: @dan-klasson I meant the implementation of the function `fetchTweets`. I'm guessing the issue is that you are not dispatching the action of type `FETCH_TWEETS_SUCCESS` inside of `fetchTweets`, but I cannot be 100% certain unless I see how you have implemented it.

Comment: ah sorry. added the action too

Comment: @dan-klasson See my updated answer, I added `mapDispatchToProps` at the end.

Comment: same problem there. `this.props.tweets[column]` is still undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184719/discussion-between-nebuler-and-dan-klasson).

Comment: funny. SO has the option to reward an already existing answer but then forces you to wait 24 hours to reward it