# Problems with React Component Reusability with Redux Store as Global State

Tags: redux, react-redux, reusability, react-component, code-reuse

I am coming across a reusability conundrum in my React/Redux app. I have coded reusable React components, such as dropdowns and sliders, and I am storing the state values in my Redux Store. It is dawning on me now that anytime any JSX instance of the component changes state, all other instances of that component also change state. They all begin to mimic each other, whereas I need them to operate independently. I also want to initialize state differently in the different instances of the component, and can't figure out a way to do this. For example, for a slider, I want the beginning and ending value of the slider range to be different in different instances of the component. This would be easy to do through React's normal props system, but I am getting confused on how to do it via Redux.

I've researched this a bit and it seems the solution is to add unique IDs to each instance of the component in the Redux store. But I need specifics on where to add the ID (the reducer? the action creator? the component?) and how to have everything flow so that the right component is getting their state changed.

This is my reducer:

```
    const INITIAL_STATE = {
      slots: 100, 
      step: 5,
      start: 35,
      end: 55,
    };

const sliderReducer = (state=INITIAL_STATE, action ) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "MIN_SELECTED":
        console.log("Min Selected");
        return {
          ...state,
          start: action.payload
        };
      case "MAX_SELECTED":
        console.log("Max Selected");
        return {
          ...state,
          end: action.payload
        };
      default:
          return state;
    }
}

export default sliderReducer;
```

this is my action creator:

```
//Slider Minimum Value Selection Action Creator
export const selectMinValue = (value) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "MIN_SELECTED",
      payload: value
    });
  };
};

//Slider Maximum Value Selection Action Creator
export const selectMaxValue = (value) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "MAX_SELECTED",
      payload: value
    });
  };
};
```

the component code is too long to paste, but it's event handlers for onDrag events and JSX for the slider essentially.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone here who runs into the same problem, there are many libraries which attempt to solve this, in my opinion, in too complex a way. The cleanest and simplest way to resolve the issue is to associate a namespace identifier with each instance of the component in the redux store. The best answer I found is here: [having multiple instance of same reusable redux react components on the same page/route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906358/having-multiple-instance-of-same-reusable-redux-react-components-on-the-same-pag)

Good luck!